# Can I wrangle this into a suitable question?

Tags: discussion

You may have heard of the C++ Business Card Ray Tracer.  http://fabiensanglard.net/rayTracing_back_of_business_card/index.php

There is a follow up in Go.  (Using gently unfortunate language, because the author improves performance at the cost of program length.)  https://kidoman.com/programming/go-getter.html

It seems like this could be a good thing to ask here: Just how small can the program be made?

I freely admit that I'm not nearly smart enough to word the question suitably, and I don't want a chameleon.  But I'd love to see the results.

So, Programming Puzzles & Code Golf - is this suitable for a question here?  And if it is, how should that question be written?

Comment: If you just want help phrasing the question try the meta sandbox (whatever version we are on now)...looks like [version 5](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/638/proposed-questions-sandbox-mk-v). That is what it is there for.

Comment: Ah, thanks dmckee.  I don't visit here often, and I wasn't aware of the sandbox.